# SQL Query to create table from 2 tables with additional columns and update records in new table whenever changes in base tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables with columns as below

tbl_BATCHING:

| SCN_ID | FUN_ID |
| --- | --- |
| SCN_001 | FUN_001 |
| SCN_001 | FUN_002 |
| SCN_001 | FUN_003 |
| SCN_002 | FUN_002 |
| SCN_002 | FUN_003 |

tbl_STEPS:

| FUN_ID | STEP_ID | STEP_DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FUN_001 | 1 | Enter User ID |
| FUN_001 | 2 | Enter Password |
| FUN_002 | 1 | Click Logout |
| FUN_002 | 2 | User should logged out and landing page should be displayed |

FUN_ID is common column in both tables.

Now I want to create new table with some columns from above tables along with additional columns

| SCN_ID | FUN_ID | STEP_ID | STEP_DESCRIPTION | SKIP_STEP | DATA_OO1 | DATA_OO2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SCN_001 | FUN_001 | 1 | Enter User ID | N | Test | Demo |
| SCN_001 | FUN_001 | 2 | Enter Password | N | 1234 | 1234 |
| SCN_002 | FUN_002 | 1 | Click Logout | N |  |  |
| SCN_002 | FUN_002 | 2 | User should logged out and landing page should be displayed | N |  |  |

SCN_ID, FUN_ID, STEP_ID and STEP_DESCRITION records will come from base tables i.e. tbl_BATCHING and tbl_STEPS. User will update other 3 columns i.e. SKIP_STEP,DATA_001, DATA_002.

Also, whenever any changes i.e. updation to existing record or new record in base table then record, same needs to be updated in new table tbl_BATCHING_STEPS.

1. Any changes in existing records i.e. 'Enter User Name' instead of 'Enter User ID'
2. New record added in base table i.e. 'Click login button' after STEP_ID 2 under FUN_ID FUN_001

Please help how to achieve the above requirement.

I am using Oracle data base and developer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't include all the columns as that violates third-normal form. Instead, just capture the additional data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl_batching_steps (
  scn_id   NOT NULL,
  step_id  NOT NULL,
  data_001 VARCHAR2(100),
  data_002 VARCHAR2(100),
  CONSTRAINT batching_steps__scn__step__fk
    FOREIGN KEY (scn_id, step_id)
    REFERENCES tbl_steps (scn_id, step_id)
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KRwy_oot)

Then when you want to **display** the data you can `JOIN` this table to the previous tables to **display** all the details in one query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl_batching b
       INNER JOIN tbl_steps s
       ON (b.fun_id = s.fun_id)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_batching_steps bs
       ON (   bs.fun_id  = s.fun_id
          AND bs.step_id = s.step_id)
```

Comment: Not getting "REFERENCES tbl_steps (scn_id, step_id)". Since, tbl_steps do not have scn_id column. 

Please note FUN_ID is common column between both base tables.
SCN_ID and FUN_ID in new table are unique records.

Also, how new table will be updated whenever any changes or new record added in base table

Comment: @Hiruthere `CONSTRAINT constraint_name FOREIGN KEY (column_list) REFERENCES table_name (another_column_list)` is how you create an (out-of-line) foreign key constraint.

Comment: @Hiruthere The point is that you do **NOT** need to update the table when there are changes to the base tables. As stated in the answer, when you want to **display** the combined tables then you use a `JOIN` and the up-to-date information from all the tables will be displayed. This allows you to keep the data in third-normal form (and not have duplicated data other than the keys necessary for referential constraints).

Comment: I am not getting the JOIN table part. For example, have new record added in tbl_STEPS table i.e. 'Click login button' after STEP_ID 2 under FUN_ID FUN_001. In this case how user will update SKIP_STEP, DATA_001, DATA_002. Since join table is only view.

Comment: @Hiruthere The same way you would do it with any set of tables, `INSERT`/`UPDATE` the appropriate values in the the `batching_steps` table.

Comment: I am new to SQL, it will be good if you give example with queries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252324/discussion-between-hiruthere-and-mt0).